# How to change 2 table row background colors based on a heading class names on the same WordPress Page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, html-table

I have a ranking table with the similar heading 2 and table such as follows:

`<h2 class="Mary-Anne">Table </h2>`

[image: table]

I am completely new to Javascript or PHP (preferably PHP or whichever suits this case). I have no idea whether this can be accomplished with CSS only. I am hoping to set a background-color:green; to the table rows depending on the h2 class names. In the table, each row is getting its class name from the Name column. Example, the second row's class name is `tr.Mary{}`. I added an hyphen between the h2 class names to separate them. Also, this should be an exact match so that the color is not assigned for partial matches such as `Ann-Paul` where the target class name is `Anne-Paul`.

I'll be grateful for any help accorded.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution that worked for me.

```
tr[class*="firstclass"]{
background: #ffff00;
}


tr[class*="secondclass"]{
background: #ffff00;
}
```